# jquery - not able to access the value of field who's ID has a dot

Tags: jquery

I have a hidden input field defined in the html. I'm accessing the value of the input field but getting `undefined`.

**HTML**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="js/myjquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <form>
      <input type="hidden" name="hidden1" value="test" id="hidden1">
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATED HTML**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>         
</head>
<body>
   <form>
       <script src="js/myjquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <input type="hidden" name="hidden1" value="test" id="hidden1">
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATED 2 HTML**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>         
</head>
<body>
   <form>
       <script src="js/myjquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <input type="hidden" name="sk.hidden1" value="test" id="sk.hidden1">
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
   var inputParam = $("input#sk.hidden1").val();
   alert(inputParam);
});
```

Comment: Not reproducible: http://jsfiddle.net/RtDTd/

Comment: Works fine for me in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qzWRz/)

Comment: Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/EKpx5/

Comment: I'm starting to think, this could be a jQuery include problem.

Comment: jQuery is being loaded relative to the page in question `src="js/jquery-1.6.4.js"` probably not what you want... change it to `src="/js/jquery-1.6.4.js"`

Comment: @SK11, your updated, HTML does not help, we don't know where `js/myjquery.js` is or any other references, try referencing google directly => `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @Frankie: but the rest of the jquery code is working fine so I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: Not sure what the "updates" are supposed to mean specifically, but "Updated 2 HTML" is not likely to work, since jQuery tends to dislike periods in ids.

Comment: Please see below for the javascript reg exp solution and my comments on the "updates".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wild guessing here but seams that you are probably not including jQuery correctly.

Try to include jQuery in the following fashion:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>         
</head>
```

**Edit:**

Even though your ID is valid it is frowned uppon because jQuery will treat that as id.class.

Meaning it is looking for a field that has ID = `sk` class = `hidden1`.

If you must work it that way you should have your selector with an escape:

```
$('#sk\\.hidden1');
```

But I would sugest you rename your ID to someting else and discard the usage of dots in ID's or classes. Use the `-` or `_` as both are supported.

[**The rules to name an ID are pretty simple:**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp)

- Must begin with a letter A-Z or a-z
- Can be followed by: letters (A-Za-z), digits (0-9), hyphens ("-"), and underscores ("_")

Comment: I don't need to do this since the rest of the jquery code is working fine.

Comment: @SK11 could your javascript be breaking prior to the usage of the following function? Meaning, you have a problem on another function that is breaking JS parsing... ? Pass the code in question to the top of your page.

Comment: @SK11 to rule out something odd about your browser please test the jsFiddle examples that we're posted as comments on your question. If they too don't work... there is something odd with your browser (and not your code).

Comment: Please see *UPDATED 2 HTML*. I figured it out. I have a "." in the ID so when I make a reference to it, it gives `undefined`. Would you know why?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
var inputParam = $("#hidden1").val();
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FHTxb/)

With `input#hidden1` it still works:

http://jsfiddle.net/FHTxb/1/  (with `input#hidden1`).

Maybe @SK11's jquery is not being included properly?

Try including jquery directly from google:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You might not even be firing jQuery `$(document).ready()`

Comment: That should not be the reason for the problem though.

Comment: I'm leaned to vote you down because even though there really is no use in giving an the ID and field as a selector... it really has nothing to do with the problem nor have I found any reference to browsers misbehaving on the usage of selectors as the OP did.

Comment: @Frankie, you are free to do so.

Comment: @Jakub on and on I'm just too greedy... ;)